# Recursively add an extension to a group of files in PowerShell Version. 4

Tags: powershell-4.0

I'm looking at how to add an extension recursively to an entire folder structure. This line does what I need, but only for the current folder. I need to do the same for the subfolders structure.

```
Get-ChildItem -File | % { mv ($_.BaseName+"") ($_.BaseName+".png") }
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Jess...\' because it does not exist.
```

I used the search, however I only founded a solution for the Bash, not the PowerShell. So I couldn't get the -Recurse to work in the same way.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | % { mv ($_.BaseName+"") ($_.BaseName+".png") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get the full pathname.  In powershell 6 this isn't an issue.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | % { $_ | mv -destination ($_.Name + '.png' ) -whatif }
```

Or

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | ? { ! $_.extension } | 
  mv -destination { $_.Name + '.png' } -whatif
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems that it is not working in the same way as the first code in my post, it's not putting the extension only in the files that doesn't have extensions.

Comment: Try the second one.